# EE won't let me post, edit, submit

Tags: control-panel, ee1

So here's something weird that's happened: the site is still generating previously created content on our site -- http://www.comicsreporter.com -- and I can get to EE, and open posts, but I can't save an edit, can't submit anything, and can't search for a posting by name. I also can't save changes to configurations -- like I can click "off" on Auto Check but it doesn't save. In all cases, saving, submitting, or searching returns me to the CP Home page.

Help? We're running an old-ass version (1.4.1), but any help via any version might be appreciated.

Comment: Stupid question: but are you super admin?

Comment: I think so, yeah; it's been like five years since i've been the one that's had to poke around this thing, but I'm pretty sure I was afforded all this stuff when we set it up.

Comment: Oof, 1.4.1? This might be one for [official EllisLab support](https://support.ellislab.com).

Comment: Are you seeing any JS errors? Have you tried a different browser? Triple check that you are SuperAdmin from inside your myaccount page.

Comment: no js errors, yes on multiple browsers, i am superadmin

Comment: Im having the same issue. new install. can get to EE, and open posts, but I can't save an edit, can't submit anything.... EE 5.3.0 the current version.

Answer (score 1):

There's a seemingly identical EE1 [post on the EL forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/81343/) for this issue. You might want to try making the [following changes](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/81343/#408935) to config.php:

```
$conf['secure_forms'] = "n";
$conf['require_ip_for_login'] = "n";
$conf['require_ip_for_posting'] = "n";
```

This will disable some useful security features but it could be a viable short term workaround.

I'd also suggest updating to the latest EE1 release (if not EE2) ASAP. I wouldn't want to guess how many bugs and compatibility issues there are in 1.4.1.

Answer (score 1):

here is the fix. this worked for me on 2.25.2020. you hosting company can do this for you.

"I have investigated the issue and checked server logs, according to them, the issue could have been caused by triggered ModSecurity rule.

ModSecurity is an Apache module which works as a web application firewall. It blocks known exploits and provides protection from a range of attacks against web applications. Sometimes ModSecurity has conflicts with some scripts and plugins which may result in false-positive blocks, thus it is not possible to predict or avoid it, unfortunately.

I whitelisted this rule for your account, so please check it on your side now."